# Extracting Font Version via WinAPI

Tags: c++, winapi, fonts

The Windows Control Panel fonts window typically displays version information for the font. e.g.

```
 Font Name: Fontawesome
 Version: Version 4.3.0 2015
```

I have searched in the Windows API and SO, but I have not managed to find how to extract this programmatically.

Any ideas?

Comment: When you say *"typically"*, you'll have to name the OS. Windows 7, 8, 8.1, and 10 do not display version information.

Comment: @IInspectable - you can see the version in the font preview window.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that if you're talking about the font preview program; that is not "Windows", that's actually just a small utility application that comes bundled with the OS. To show you that information, it consults information from the font's `name` table ([spec here, for understanding its structure](https://www.microsoft.com/typography/otspec/name.htm), with the semantics of each `record id` explained in the "Name IDs" section).

To access this data yourself, use DirectWrite's (not GDI, because it's ancient and obsolete) [IDWriteFontFace::TryGetFontTable](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd371039%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method, and get a reference to the `name` table, which every valid OpenType font contains. Then extract the values you need as per the spec for the naming table.

And to be clear: **both** `ttf` and `otf` fonts are OpenType fonts, the first is just "OpenType with outlines encoded using the TrueType table layout" and the second is "OpenType with outlines encoded using a CFF data block". If you don't know what the difference between those two is, that's because the difference doesn't matter: it's as if we decided to call PNG files `nil` and `ili` files depending on whether they used interlacing or not.

(The `ttf` file extension simply predates the OpenType spec itself, and so when everyone switched to OpenType fonts, the extension was kept for backward compatibility. After several decades now, it turns out it's way easier to just keep doing that instead of deciding "when to get rid of it", so we're stuck with both extensions being used for the same kind of file. History!)

Comment: Thank you for your great answer. Unfortunately, although I've got some initial stuff building, I've not managed to understand how I should be using 'openTypeTableTag' parameter, and there seem to be minimal samples/documentation out there for this API!

Comment: you're trying to extract the 'name' table, using (as per the documentation link) the following macro to form the tag argument for the table: [`DWRITE_MAKE_OPENTYPE_TAG('n','a','m','e')`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd368103%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)

Comment: Thanks Mike! I did manage to get there in the end and the data even seems to be correct :) I found the "wine" code snippets that I found on google pointed in the right direction.

Answer (score 0):

If you have a [IDWriteFont](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nn-dwrite-idwritefont) instance, you can call [IDWriteFont::GetInformationalStrings](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/nf-dwrite-idwritefont-getinformationalstrings) with [DWRITE_INFORMATIONAL_STRING_VERSION_STRINGS](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/dwrite/ne-dwrite-dwrite_informational_string_id)